# How to create a sinusoidal signal with additive White Gaussian Noise (WGN) and dump the dataset to a text file?

Tags: matlab

1. The scripts, first create a sine data set for `t = [0:0.1:2]` with `1Hz` frequency.
2. Then, it adds a `Gaussian random` data whose `mean is 0` and `standard deviation is 0.5` to the **sine** data.
3. Plots both dataset on the same figure.
4. At the end, writes all noisy sinusoidal data to the file called
   `data.csv` using a `for loop` and `fprintf` function.

I wrote this but i want to use `randn`.

```
>>frequenciy = [1];
>>curTime = 0; 
>>h = 0.01;
>>for i = 1:length(frequenciy)
    endTime = curTime + 2*pi/frequenciy(i);
    t = [0:0.1:2];
    shift = frequenciy(i)*t(1);
    curTime = endTime;
    plot(t,sin(frequenciy(i)*t-shift))
    hold on
>>end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop.

Try this:

```
t = 0:0.01:4;

f = 1; %Hz
w = 2*pi*f; 

s = sin(w*t); % original signal with frequency 1Hz
noise = randn(size(s)); % white noise with mu=0, sigma = 1
noise = noise*0.5; % sigma correction
s_noisy = s + noise;

%plot
figure
plot(t, s);
hold on;
plot(t, s_noisy);
hold off;
grid minor;

% save to file
fileID = fopen('sine.csv','w');
fprintf(fileID, '%6.4f\n', s_noisy);
fclose(fileID);
```

[image]